# append table row to another table row

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup on the page. I want to append two more table rows right after this one.

```
<tr><td width="48%" align="right" nowrap=""><b>Type it again:</b></td><td width="52%"> <input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" size="20" name="passwordagain"><!-- value="" --></td></tr>
```

Here are the two I want to append to the first one above

```
<tr><td width="48%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><b>First Name:</b></td><td width="52%"> <input maxlength="35" value="" size="30" name="BillingFirstName"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="48%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Last Name:</b></td><td width="52%"> <input name="BillingLastName" size="30" value="" maxlength="35"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know exactly what the two new rows should be, here's a quick and dirty way:

```
$('tr:has(:input[name=passwordagain])') // row in question: no ID to use?
  .after('<tr><td>...First Name...</td></tr>') // to add
  .next()                                      // don't reverse order
  .after('<tr><td>...Last Name...</td></tr>'); // next to add
```

You could omit the `next()` and simply put the `.after()`s in reverse order, or stick them in the same string, or any number of other variations.

Based on your comment, [here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfqc3/) that should clarify what's going on.

Comment: That's meant to be shorthand -- meaning, "all that other stuff in the 'First Name' row goes here". The entirety of the `<tr>` you want to insert goes inside the `.after()` call, and will be inserted by jQuery immediately after the row with "passwordagain". I did show "first name" twice; the second one was meant to be "last name". Fixed that.

Comment: @user, check out the jsFiddle referenced above in my answer. It shows a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$('table').append('<tr>row 1</tr><tr>row 2</tr>');
```

where `table` is the parent table. You may have to use `tbody` if you have that in your table instead.